Google OAuth 2.0 - Invalid Scope Error for Google Wallet API (wallet_object.issuer)
I'm trying to use the Google Wallet API to generate custom passes, but I'm encountering an issue with the OAuth 2.0 authorization process. When I request the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer scope, I get an invalid_scope error. Here are the steps I've followed and the issue details:
Steps Followed

Enabled Google Wallet API:

Went to Google Cloud Console.
Navigated to APIs & Services > Library.
Enabled the Google Wallet API for my project.


Configured OAuth Consent Screen:

Filled in required fields in the consent screen.
Tried to add the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer scope but received an error stating it’s an invalid scope.


Created OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials:

Selected Web application as the application type.
Added http://localhost:5173/oauth2callback as the authorized redirect URI.


Generated Authorization URL:

Used the Google OAuth2Client to generate the authorization URL with the following scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer





Code Snippet (Node.js/Express)
app.get('/generate-auth-url', (req, res) => {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer']
  });
});

Issue
When accessing the generated authorization URL, I receive the following error:

Documentation Reference
The scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/wallet_object.issuer is documented in the Google Wallet API documentation.
Attempted Workaround
I also tried using the OAuth 2.0 Playground to manually obtain tokens with the required scope, but encountered the same issue with the invalid_scope error.

Any idea on how to tackle this issue? I'm starting to think this is a bug from Google's side.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
